# C# how to dynamicaly make treeview from json file

Tags: c#, json, winforms, treeview

I am trying o use a tree view in a winform with c# to allow selection of servers in data centers for a small inventory of applications. I am using the following .json as a locally stored hard coded file of the application inventory.

```
{
  "App1": {
    "DataCenter1": [ "DC1_serverA", "DC1_serverB", "DC1_serverC" ],
    "DataCenter2": [ "DC2_serverX", "DC2_serverY", "DC2_serverZ" ]
  },
  "App2": {
    "DataCenter1": [ "DC1_serverQ", "DC1_serverR", "DC1_serverT" ],
    "CDC2": [ "DC2_serverM", "DC2_serverN", "DC2_serverP" ]
  }
}
```

I am using c# to iterate over this json to create dynamically the tree view to allow users to select what apps/ data center/ server they want. my high level code, where I cant figure the leaf level logic to extract the data is this:

```
dynamic dynJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(File.ReadAllText(@"servers.json"));            
foreach (var item in dynJson)
{
    TreeNode treeNodeCI = new TreeNode(item);
    treCIListing.Nodes.Add(treeNodeCI);
}
```

I seem to be using the wrong handle to get at the items in the json. I can edit the .json file format to be more suitable and easier in c# to turn the data into a UI of selectable items like this picture attached. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to go recursively for ex.

```
private void FillTree(TreeNode parentNode, IEnumerable dynJson)
{
  foreach (var item in dynJson)
  {
    TreeNode treeNodeCI = new TreeNode(item);
    FillTree(treeNodeCI, item);
    parentNode.Nodes.Add(treeNodeCI);
  }
}
```

then the initial call should be something like:

```
dynamic dynJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(File.ReadAllText(@"servers.json"));
FillTree(treCIListing, dynJson);
```

You can handle the types more specifically than I, I am using IEnumerable and TreeNode but you can use your specifics types

Comment: that's pretty much what I am doing but the item is not what should be added to get desired results. c# fails to add items as the syntax is off on the line to add nodes.